# What port should I assign to the socket call in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, sockets, networking, port

Basically, Im learning how the socket class works in AS3, seems pretty simple, but I dont know what port to assign in the second connect() parameter, let say I wanna load a image from the web, what should I have to do to figure what port is the right one?

Thx!

Comment: To load images into flash you "generally" need the server to have a crossdomain.xml policy file in the server root.

Comment: Your question is also rather vague.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend entirely on the server you are connecting to, what port are they listening on? Since you are talking about loading images, I'll assume you are connecting to a web server, they typically run on port 80, or 443 if it is using https.

Note however, unless the server is serving up SocketPolicy files, you will not be able to connect to the server due to Flash Player security settings. More on Socket Policies here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html

Comment: Let say, for example, I want to load this image: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_167-sL7Cczk/TBiMz6jdtYI/AAAAAAAABcs/JxqC2vCIFa4/s1600/cute-puppy-dog-wallpapers.jpg what would be the port?

Comment: The port is 80, its a standard web server.

Comment: See my comment above about Socket Policy files.

Comment: This isn't totally correct. port 443 is the default port for the master crosdomain policy. Flash player will attempt to retrieve the policy file on whatever port you are trying to connect from first. So basically the first connection is a a request to the server in the form of <policy-file-request/> at this time it will keep the socket open until a response is given. If you requests data to be sent the response is not the policy file and the flash play will close the connection and all subsequent transactions will be blocked,

Comment: however the data from the first response will still be there will not be lost. So need less to say it would more practical to serve up the crossdomain policy file on the port that the socket is connecting on.

Comment: my knowledge could well be out of date, but my understanding is it looks on port 843 first, and only other ports if explicitly told to do so in AS code, or if the response on port 843 tells it to do so. I know you can no longer specify it in regular cross domain files.

Comment: regardless though, that server is running on port 80.